# Should the @PreDestroy method of TransactionScoped beans run before or after the transaction ends?

Tags: quarkus

According to the "[Using transactions in Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction)" guide, the `@PreDestroy` method of TransactionScoped beans gets invoked before the transaction ends ([source](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/3.5.0/docs/src/main/asciidoc/transaction.adoc?plain=1#L332-L335)), however, [this test class](https://github.com/jl-martins/quarkus-transaction-scoped-tests/blob/f27b1df6bc1f0aeb63b33efd019f0fd82a7e754b/src/test/java/org/example/TransactionScopedTest.java) seems to suggest otherwise. With that in mind, I wonder if the `@PreDestroy` method should get invoked before the transaction ends, as stated in the official documentation, or after, as the tests I've shared seem to suggest.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Jakarta Transactions, but I believe the Quarkus documentation you're refering to is incorrect. The specification (https://jakarta.ee/specifications/transactions/2.0/jakarta-transactions-spec-2.0#transactionscoped-annotation) says that the transaction scope is active also when the transaction is in state "committing" or "rolling back", which makes sense -- the scope is active as long as the transaction exists. It is only when the transaction completes (that is, after commit or rollback) that the instances in the transaction CDI context are destroyed.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @Ladicek!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however, this test class seems to suggest otherwise

I've just tried your test and I can confirm that in Quarkus the `@TransactionScoped` beans are destroyed after the transaction is commited/rolled back.

The JTA spec states that *"Any Synchronization.afterCompletion methods will be invoked in an undefined context."*. But it does not explicitly define when exactly `@TransactionScoped` beans are destroyed.

I've created https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/36880 to track this issue.